# Export datatable to excel format using jquery

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

I have a data table. It should be exported to a excel file .The excel file to which it should be exported  is not a default excel format. I have a template with some messages in it. The data in my data table should be populated to the table present in the excel sheet(Excel sheet contains other messages along with tables.). I have to achieve this using jquery and ajax calls. If I use datatable jquery API, I am able to export it to default excel format but not in the way I want.Can someone suggest me a solution??

Comment: Which Language you using for server side?

Comment: I use C# on the server side

Comment: Please provide the template you want to export as.

Comment: Its an excel sheet with some text at the bottom.I am not able to post images here.